# Is there an application for closing down a program upon a certain action?

Tags: windows-7

I don't really know how to explain this, so let me tell you exactly what I am trying to do.

I am doing some game programming and wanted to use cheat engine to see some things.

However, I also love to play Team Fortress 2. I don't want my account to get banned by VAC. Which it would do if TF2 and Cheat Engine were running at the same time.

So is there an application for windows 7 that would allow me to detect steam being started and automatically close cheat engine if steam were started?

If that is not good enough of a description, let me know and I will update. Thanks!

Comment: i would have used an other approach to handle that. i would have created a different account (Windows User Account) 1 for Gaming and 1 for Developing. I think the great plus you will have the full system Power for Gaming without running unused Developer Tool Prozesses during gaming.

Comment: @DaveRook Computer code is fine. I just don't want the application up unless I am using it on my own stuff. If I wanted to cheat... I wouldn't need to do this...

Comment: @konqui I will try that, thanks for the suggestion. I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a very simple thing: create a .bat file for open steam!
Here an example on how it can work:

```
taskkill /IM CheatEngine.exe
C:\Steam\Steam.exe
```

So opening this bat it will close your CheatEngine and open steam, it works even without administrative rights. Remember to use the correct .exe name and the correct path for steam!

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. He user isn't asking how to close CheatEngine at the same time manually, he's asking how to detect that Steam is being started programatically.

Comment: @DaveRook ok i missed the target, hope the new answer will fullfill the OP request

Comment: I think this is a very good answer. It actually solves OP's problem and isn't an overkill. That's exactly what I would do.

Comment: This is actually probably the best answer. I will have to get back to you. I was actually trying not to write a program. Haha, and I would do it in Java anyways. Thank you, will test and get back to you.

Comment: @HypeZ Here is what I did. timeout /T 10 - taskkill /IM cheat.exe - start /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\steam\" steam.exe. Thanks for the help, didn't think of that.

Comment: Let me add to that. I actually had to use something else for cheat engine. (Crafty little app, haha) this command will work - C:\WINDOWS\System32\tskill.exe cheat*

Answer (score 1):

Ok looks like my first answer doesn't got the real problem. So, i don't know if there is an application that can close your cheat engine when steam starts, but i do know how to do one. I'm assuming you have a little **C#** programming experience and Visual Studio installed.

Open **Visual Studio**, create a new project (a service would be a 100% perfect usage for your case, you can google on how to create a service) and select new **wpf application**, i tested it with target framework **.net 4.0** but newer version will work too

Download source code from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI

Copy-paste `ProcessInfo.cs` into your project (you can import the **.cs** file or manually copy paste it into a new class)

In your `public MainWindow()`, after `InitializeComponent()` paste this

```
Win32Process.ProcessInfo steam = new Win32Process.ProcessInfo("steam.exe");
steam.Started += new Win32Process.ProcessInfo.StartedEventHandler(this.SteamStarted);
```

Create this new function

```
private void SteamStarted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("cheatengine.exe"))
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

Done! Hope this is the answer you needed